# How to avoid creation of duplicates in data.table when using aggregation operations

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with a `data.table` object to make some aggregation operations faster. The real size of my dataset is more than 100 millon rows so I include dummy data for this question. My `data.table` object is `Sample3` (I add `dput()` version in the final side) which is composed of 5 variables: `Date`, `Id`, `Value`, `Week` and `Day`. I want to perform an aggregation task by `Id` and `Week` in order to compute `Number`: number of rows, `Sum`: total sum of value, `Avg`: average of value and `Diff`: difference between `Day` and maximum `Date`. I used next code for that task:

```
library(data.table)
#Compute
Summary <- Sample3[,.(Number=.N,Sum=sum(Value),Avg=mean(Value),
                                          Diff=Day-max(Date)),by = .(Id,Week)]
```

The computing is correct but there is an issue, `Summary` has duplicated rows, when the desired output should have only 1 observation according to `Id` and `Week`. Also, `Sample3` has 11 rows and `Summary` has the same number of rows. I am not using the `:=` operator. This is the output I get:

```
       Id    Week Number       Sum      Avg   Diff
 1: 923996 48-2014      5 21.690579 4.338116 5 days
 2: 923996 48-2014      5 21.690579 4.338116 5 days
 3: 923996 48-2014      5 21.690579 4.338116 5 days
 4: 923996 48-2014      5 21.690579 4.338116 5 days
 5: 923996 48-2014      5 21.690579 4.338116 5 days
 6: 923996 49-2014      3 22.115795 7.371932 2 days
 7: 923996 49-2014      3 22.115795 7.371932 2 days
 8: 923996 49-2014      3 22.115795 7.371932 2 days
 9: 923996 50-2014      1  5.101146 5.101146 3 days
10: 923996 51-2014      2  6.086128 3.043064 1 days
11: 923996 51-2014      2  6.086128 3.043064 1 days
```

The correct output for `Summary` should look like this:

```
     Id    Week Number       Sum      Avg   Diff
1: 923996 48-2014      5 21.690579 4.338116 5 days
2: 923996 49-2014      3 22.115795 7.371932 2 days
3: 923996 50-2014      1  5.101146 5.101146 3 days
4: 923996 51-2014      2  6.086128 3.043064 1 days
```

I do not know why is happening this behavior with this single operation and having duplicated rows in a big dataset could lead to more time in the task of removing them. It is like every row is being updated. The `dput()` version of `Sample3` is next:

```
Sample3 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(16405, 16405, 16406, 16406, 
16406, 16407, 16409, 16409, 16415, 16421, 16424), class = "Date"), 
    Id = c(923996L, 923996L, 923996L, 923996L, 923996L, 923996L, 
    923996L, 923996L, 923996L, 923996L, 923996L), Value = c(5.69822266467209, 
    3.11110428877822, 4.74334486914574, 2.17729208527479, 5.96061541361928, 
    7.60801375507644, 4.3689394081637, 10.1388420642027, 5.10114642099159, 
    0.022944125999933, 6.06318436387287), Week = c("48-2014", 
    "48-2014", "48-2014", "48-2014", "48-2014", "49-2014", "49-2014", 
    "49-2014", "50-2014", "51-2014", "51-2014"), Day = structure(c(16411, 
    16411, 16411, 16411, 16411, 16411, 16411, 16411, 16418, 16425, 
    16425), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000311ef0>)
```

I am new in the use of `data.table` and maybe this is a very easy solution but I have searched other posts without finding a way to amend this situation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting multiple rows is because this code results in a vector rather than a single value:

```
Diff=Day-max(Date)
```

All you need is `[1]` (or `min`)

```
library(data.table)
Sample3[,.(Number=.N,Sum=sum(Value),Avg=mean(Value),
            Diff=Day[1]-max(Date)),by = .(Id,Week)] 
#       Id    Week Number       Sum      Avg   Diff
#1: 923996 48-2014      5 21.690579 4.338116 5 days
#2: 923996 49-2014      3 22.115795 7.371932 2 days
#3: 923996 50-2014      1  5.101146 5.101146 3 days
#4: 923996 51-2014      2  6.086128 3.043064 1 days
```

As @Uwe notes there are functions in `data.table` that may assist in optimizing the speed of your code such as `first` and `last` if your data is already arranged by Date.

Comment: Perhaps, you can add that `data.table` has the `first()` and `last()` functions?